# set cookie to check if 1 of 2 links has been clicked and pass JS

Tags: javascript, cookies, viewport

(please note: client request for the below are out of my hands)

I'm currently working on a site that's going to have a 'mobile view' and a 'desktop view'. I've set this up using jQuery to edit the meta viewport data depending on what's being clicked

```
$( '.desktop-site-link' ).click(function() {
   viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
   viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1024');
   return false;
});
$( '.mobile-site-link' ).click(function() {
    viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
    return false;
});
```

What I now want to do is add a cookie to check if the sites 'on desktop' or 'on mobile if selected via the link option (in the footer) so that if the user goes to a new page they get their 'chosen' site 'design'.

Any ideas? I've been looking at this - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie - but not sure what data I'd need to add to make a new page show the 'desktop' or 'mobile' view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to implement - just store a cookie eg `mobile` and check if it exists on load

```
var makeMobile = function() {
    viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
    $.cookie("mobile", true, { path: '/' }));
    return false;
}

var makeDesktop = function() {
   viewport = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
   viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1024');
   $.cookie("mobile", false, { path: '/' });
   return false;
}

if($.cookie("mobile")) {
   makeMobile();
} else if($.cookie("mobile") === false) {
   makeDesktop();
}

$( '.desktop-site-link' ).click(makeDesktop);
$( '.mobile-site-link' ).click(makeMobile);
```